Borderless Print to PDF from Excel
I want to export an excel sheet to a PDF. I do so with the following VBA code (the comments are just some things I tried):
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet).Select
    
    'ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:A320"
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        '.Zoom = False
        '.FitToPagesTall = 1
        '.FitToPagesWide = 1
        '.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        '.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        '.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
        '.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    End With
    
    Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne00:"

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=filepath & "_noFont.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

My problem is that the pdf has a border at the bottom and on the left side regardeless of my margin-settings.
Bottom left of the PDF
I would prefer for a solution which is not dependent on the computer used to execute the code.
Let me know if you need more information.
System details:

Excel 2019 Version 2312 (Build 17126.20132) 64-bit

I’ve tried:

Set Custom Margins to 0
Use Microsoft Print to PDF as Printer:
Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne00:"
Specifically define PrintArea:
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:A64"
Define Scaling as fot to: 1 page wide by 1 page tall:
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.FitToPagesWide = 1
Disable “Scale Content for A4 paper sizes” (Options\Advanced\General)
Check default paper size: A4 with limits set to 0,00 cm


TBC you want the page to be all green and the white border is the problem? Or do you want the sheet to be white and there's the green border, Apologies if this isn't obvious I only saw the bottom corner of your sheet and one is much easier than the other.

@MarkS. I want the page to be all green ;) Give me a sec, I quickly create the pdf with a monocrome image so I can share all of the A4 page.

[https://superuser.com/questions/954768/full-page-background-for-excel][1] this may be a helpful link on the subject

@MarkS.
How it looks in Excel:
enter image description here
How it looks as a PDF:
enter image description here

Are your margins set to 0 on all sides?

@MarkS. Yes, my margins are set to 0
